# Why Rstudio compiler looking for R headers in the wrong include directories?

Tags: c++, r, gcc, header

The compiler wants to include R.h header file. These header files come installed with R, so obviously, the include is in the R installation dir.

But while trying to install a package, the compiler is looking at the wrong paths (though I added the path in my env vars):

```
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'~/R/win-library/3.6/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include" -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c dummy.cc -o dummy.o
gcc  -I"/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'~/R/win-library/3.6/sp/include' -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include" -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c init.c -o init.o
init.c:1:10: fatal error: R.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <R.h>
      |          ^~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Is there any way to make the compiler look at the include path specified in my env vars?

---

/s/ is a dependency for rgeos package:

```
install.packages("~/R/win-library/3.6/rgeos_0.6-4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

I had to transfer R headers from R install dir to /sp/ so the compiler can find them. I shouldn't have to do that...

Comment: I addition to what @r2evans said, you have a wrong version of RTools installed. The version of RTools needs to match the version of R, and yours doesn’t.

Comment: @r2evans, I use 4.3.1, the 3.6 is just the folder leftover that R reused to install 4.3.1 files. Version output (version.string R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt) . Also, anytime, i tried to install a package or depenceny, Rstudio prompt me to reinstall it for versioni 4.3.1

Comment: Okay, I see ... you're trying to use _some_ headers from `sp` in an old old version of R ... my apologies for going down the wrong path.

Comment: `rgeos` has been intentionally retired. Is there a reason you don't want to update to the modern `sp` and/or `sf` that has subsumed `rgeos`?

Comment: FYI, it looks like you believe that `R.h` is within `rtools43/x86.../include`. On one of my older systems, it's installed with R itself, not with Rtools. I don't have windows with R-4.3, just R-4.2 (I don't use it regularly), but on that system it's `C:/R/R-4.2.3/include/R.h`. Are you certain you are pointing to a directory that contains `R.h`?

Comment: @r2evans: rgeos is itself a depencency for eechidna: ``` install.packages("~/R/win-library/3.6/eechidna_1.4.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") ```  . The author has required these dependencies. Also, your question is my question (Since the R.h header is in R itself, why is the compiler looking for it in rtools?

Comment: I see, you're trying to install two archived packages. You may be able to install them via devtools, perhaps `devtools::install_packages("cran/rgeos")` and either `devtools::install_packages("cran/eechidna")` or `devtools::install_packages("jforbes14/eechidna")` (not sure which is usable atm).

Comment: FYI, the author was notified a year ago about the impending retirement, and they did not update their package. This is unfortunate, perhaps you can add your name to [eechidna#40](https://github.com/jforbes14/eechidna/issues/40) to request updates.

Comment: @r2evans: Thank you . Got error running your first command "Error: 'install_packages' is not an exported object from 'namespace:devtools'"

Comment: Oops, `devtools::install_github`, sry about that

Comment: @r2evans: Thank you . Still failed due to compilation error "-lgeos -LC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -L/bin/x64 -lR
C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lR: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rgeos'"

Comment: It sounds like you're still messing with the makevars and/or include paths. I can find `collect2.exe` deep within the rtools directory, and since Rtools goes to great pains to control the paths and such during compilation, it should be finding it. Said differently, I think I'm out ... I don't have the ability to test a nonstandard install on a windows machine, am not a C++ guru anyway, compiles on windows can tend to be finicky, and even disregarding all of that ... your question is currently not reproducible, I don't know what changes you're making.

Comment: @r2evans:  collect2.exe as well as ld.exe do exist within "C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin", however the path fetched by the compiler includes a back slash just before filename instead of a forward slash for windows. The path should be :"C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin\ld.exe  not: C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe

Comment: In my (past) experience with R on windows, that does not pose a problem, but I cannot confirm that it is still the case.

Comment: I suggest you deinstall and reinstall Rtools. The installer should adjust the PATH and you shouldn't need to mess with the PATH manually (at least if you install Rtools in `C:/`). Are you sure that you are using an R version matching your installed Rtools version (check in the RStudio options)?

Comment: @Roland, I just installed Rtools43 yesterday and is matching with R.4.3.1 version. I previously had Rtools in C:\ (they're still there, but the system is correctly defaulting now to rtools43

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was indeed a cluttered environment variables and installation system.
Here's what I have done and hopefully it helps someone:

1. Uninstalled the old Rtools (kept Rtools43
2. Modified past refs in environment variables (reset R_HOME and R_LIBS_USER):

```
R_HOME        C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1  (it was pointing to old 3.6.2 version
R_LIBS_USER   C:\Users\Your-USERNAME\Documents\R\win-library\4.3 (was pointing to 3.6
```

> **Note:** Above entries are NOT under the path, which might skip you.
> This will affect your compiler, even if your path is pointing correctly.
> Unfortunately, your program compiler will not report this issue. it might show you the correct path but it doesn't mean it was not redirected by an old RSTUDIO refs to another path.>

3. Modifying the path:

**C:\rtools43\usr\bin**

(instead of just C:\rtools43

3. Modifying ~/.Renviron (tilde is whatever the output of):

```
Sys.getenv("HOME")
```

add:

```
PATH="${RTOOLS43_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"
```

and save.

Reboot your system. If RTOOLS43_HOME entry doesn't show on the environment variables, just add it explicitly:

```
RTOOLS43_HOME  C:\rtools43
```

***Note, above entry is NOT to be put in the path.***
I added it to both system and user vars just in case the latter doesn't have some permissions.

On Rstudio, under Tools/Install Packages/Install to Library:

should have as default entry the value of R_LIBS_USER from above.

Finally, the output of `.libPaths()` should only include reachable and active/used paths for a)libraries install dir and  b)R dir.

```
.libPaths()

[1] "C:/Users/YOUR-USERNAME/Documents/R/win-library/4.3" "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/library"
```

Above paths are specific to Windows 10. Yours will be dependent on your system.

If you did EVERYTHING as suggested here. You can now run a successful install such as:

```
> install.packages("~/R/win-library/4.3/rgeos_0.6-4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Without the compiler breaking on ya.
Good luck and don't forget to thumb UP this answer if you found it useful. So it will be recommended to others. Thanks in advance!